# Packaging AIR application. Trouble with signing

Tags: macos, air, certificate, package, code-signing

Have some troubles with keystore file.

I make a request for certificate, using Keychain app.
Then I added a certificate in developer.apple site, using my request for certificate.
Then I downloaded certificate, and imported it into Keychain app.
Then I exported *.p12 file from this certificate, using Keychain assistant.
And this *.p12 file I am using to package my app. And when I do so, it raise an error:

```
Failed to package AIR application MyApp.app:
Unable to build a valid certificate chain for the signer.
```

Then I found this guy http://scottgaertner.com/code_signing/

And using his guide, I had a new error:

```
Failed to package AIR application MyApp.app:
Packaging failed. Packager internal error
```

Can anyone give me some advices?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14

UPD: Flash Builder 4.7 throws same error